# update a column with condition thru Sql Query

Tags: sql

I have column A B C D

I am trying to update Column C with divide functionality

e.g.

If Column C contains value 0.9 then i want to update that value in to 1/0.9= 1.33333 (round it to 1.3)

So the column has to update from 0.9 to 1.3.

Is there a way to do by `SQL` query with out store procedure?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't indicated which database you are using, I will offer a query that works for both mysql, postgres and sqlserver (that covers most database instances):

```
UPDATE mytable SET
columnC = CAST( 1 / columnC AS DECIMAL(8,1))
WHERE columnC = 0.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table SET columnC = 1 / columnC where columnC = 0.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember to cast your values to proper ones if they are not.

```
UPDATE tabl1e SET columnC = ROUND(1 / 0.9, 2) WHERE columnC = 0.9;
```

Also, `1/0.9` rounded to 2 decimal places gives `1,11`